# Issue with updation of the value of Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to push some data on the Firebase real-time database, but the issue I am facing is that it isn't updating the images attribute value after the upload of the image (the image has a default value of defaultimg). Instead of updating the value, the new node is getting added with the value of image.

Below is the code.

```
private void postAd(final String title,final String description,final String category,final
        String price) {
    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String uid = currentUser.getUid();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdvertData");
    HashMap<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    userMap.put("title", title);
    userMap.put("description",description);
    userMap.put("category",category);
    userMap.put("image","defaultimg");
    userMap.put("price",price);

    mDatabase.push().setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                mProgess.hide();
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(),"Data Uploaded Successfully",Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mTitle.getEditText().setText(null);
                mDescription.getEditText().setText(null);
                mPrice.getEditText().setText(null);
                mCategory.setText("Category");
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(),"Data Uploaded Unuccessfully",Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

The above code part is for uploading the data to database

The below would be for the onActivityResult method to update the image in the  child.

```
mImageStorage.child("ad_images").child(current_user_id+".jpg")
  .getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference adRef = mUserRef.child("AdvertData");
        String key = adRef.push().getKey();

        if (key != null) {
            adRef.child(key).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl)
              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        mProgess.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ad picture uploaded completely.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: `adRef.push().getKey()` creates a new key. I think you want to use the existing key instead.

Comment: Yes sir I need to get the existing key, to update the  value of the image but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after working for 6 hours on the application, I arrived at a solution, instead of getting the randomly generated key from the firebase to update the value of the image. I just Uploaded the image everytime the user data was getting uploaded to the firebase. So in short instead of updating the image in OnActivityResult of camera activity, I uploaded the image at th e time of data being uploaded to realtime database.